# Multi Threaded Server

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networkstream

I've implemented a server, and am now attempting to make it multi threaded however have come across a problem in that the server fails when data is received and that the `StreamWriter` cannot read the data from the `Stream`.

The code is as follows:

```
class whereisServer
{
    static Socket connection;
    static object threadLock = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        t.Start();
    }

    static void Run()
    {
        NetworkStream socketStream;
        TcpListener listener;
        const int PORT = 43;
        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
                socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);
                try
                {
                    connection.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
                    connection.SendTimeout = 1000;
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoRequest));
                    t.Start(socketStream);
                    //DoRequest(socketStream);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\nTimeOut Handled");
                }
                finally
                {
                    socketStream.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    static void DoRequest(object stream)
    {
        NetworkStream socketStream = (NetworkStream)stream;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(socketStream);

        lock (threadLock)
        {
             //DO SERVER STUFF HERE
        }
```

When calling the `DoRequest` method without threads the program runs fine, however when commenting that out and calling the threaded version this is when the problems occur.

I would be grateful if someone could suggest as to why the `Stream` is unable to function.

Comment: It would help if you gave us your error message.. we can only guess what the problem is otherwise.

Comment: The exception says that the "stream was not writable. Additionally it says that my StreamWriter and StreamReader are equal to null although I have created them.  This code works fine though when I don't use the threading.

Answer (score 1):

In multithreaded case you call the `Close` methods sooner than `DoRequest` does its work.

It is because these two lines are in finally block.

```
socketStream.Close();
connection.Close();
```

These two lines are executed immediately after the `Start` method starts the new thread, but before that thread completes its work in `DoRequest`.

I would recommend you to call these methods inside `DoRequest`. You can pass `connection` object into `DoRequest`, then create `socketStream` internally in `DoRequest` and when you are finished, close both these objects before finishing the `DoRequest` method. (Or you can use any other solution, this is just one option.)

Comment: Thank you, that works except I can only pass one parameter through the Start method on the Thread, of which I am currently passing the NetworkStream.  How would you recommend closing the connections inside the DoRequest method.

Thank you

Comment: You can use try-finally inside DoRequest.

Comment: OK thank you, I have been able to implement this, but since I have started using the threaded version, my DoRequest method has stopped functioning correctly.  It is expected to update a person's location when entered from the client, however it doesn't anymore.  My DoRequest method is can be found here:
http://codeshare.io/ZQpgy